# Executing shell commands with javascript

Tags: javascript, shell, unix

I know it's not possible to execute shell commands on the clients browser via js.But I was wondering if it's possible if in the client side is not a browser instead an application that just fetchs webpages?
thanks for your time guys!

Comment: you are speaking of nodejs application, so yes you can.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html take a look at https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be to use a [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) app

Node can be used to run javascript for everything in your computer, so, answering your question, you could, say, make an aplication that fetches webpages and run selected commands in the code that would be rejected by the browser.

But, if actually your goal is to just use javascript like a general use interpreted language (like say, python), you can just use js with node normally (ie, make your foo.js file and run from command line `node ./foo.js`

You can also use it as a [server](http://blog.modulus.io/build-your-first-http-server-in-nodejs) for web applications